# Expressing "from A to B" in a more concise way

Tags: word-usage, particle

In Korean, the simplest way to express 'from A to B' is no doubt 'A부터 B까지', or '부터' could be replaced by '에서' as in "A에서 B까지'.

However, this requires adding a particle to both nouns. Is there a single word that I can use, without necessarily acting as a particle, to express the same meaning in the following sentence:

> 서울에서 부산까지 몇 킬로(미터)입니까? How many kilometers (How far) is it from Seoul to Busan?

That is, I am looking to change 'A부터 B까지' to an interchangeable structure such as "A (a particle) B," just like we can do with 'A와 B' -> 'A 및 B' and 'A나 B' -> 'A 또는 B'.

Comment: Can you give an example sentence of what "multilingual stuffs" might be?

Comment: @msg45f ignore my situation and could you tell me if there is a word which can express the same meaning?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is "no", but it's hard to prove a negative.

Answer (score 1):

I see you want to get rid of the "까지" in the "A에서/부터 B까지" construction. It's true that "까지" doesn't serve much purpose when there's "에서" or "부터" other than making it more grammatical, because "에서/부터" is enough to imply the source-to-destination relation.

This is actually *often* done, by native speakers, by omission. Such a "까지" can be replaced with a comma, a brief pause.

> 이거 타면 서울에서 부산, 얼마나 걸려요?

If you're talking about the *distance* between the two, usually the word "거리" ("*distance*") gets in, to clarify that in the contracted, "까지"-dropped sentence. For semantic reinforcement.

> A에서 B, 몇 킬로(미터) **거리**예요?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen such kind of expressions that always refer to preposition 'to' in one word.

'To' is basically '조사[助詞]' and one 조사 follows only one noun. So "A to B" cannot be like A 와 B.

과/와/랑/이랑/하고/및/ are conjunction(접속사), so they are different to 조사.

Comment: I don't think your post answers the question. What do you mean by "only B is dependent on 'to' in structure 'A to B'" and "to think chunks in smaller size" and "each can be used even without the other though there is a standard form as you know"?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is a way, unfortunately. If, as you said, 부터/까지 is the easiest, why not just use that? 학교에서 집까지 얼마나 걸입니까? Nothing else is mandatory there.

Answer (score 0):

**(1)**

It takes 3 hours from Seoul to Busan by a car.

(A) **서울에서 부산까지** 차로 3시간 걸린다.

It takes 13 hours between Seoul and Washington by an airplane.

(B) **서울과 워싱턴은** (=서울과 워싱턴 사이는) 비행기로 13시간이다.

@ I believe that people are familiar to say after indicating a standard point (cf (A)).

Sometimes, in private blog or homepage, we can see a sentence like
(B) in article introducing his private thing and not focusing on tour information.

**(2)** Add

볼링핀들 사이 간격은 좁다. It is narrow between bowling pins

지척에 있는 (=아주 가까이 있는) 구봉산과 엄광산. Very small distance between Gubong Mt and Umkwang Mt.

적과의 거리는 걸어서 하루 걸린다. From here to enemy, it takes a day
by a walk.