# If 일 할 날 is "the day on which work will be done", is it possible to say "the day until which work will be done" with a similar construction?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

I believe the most obvious translation of 일 할 날 would be "the day **on which** work will be done", or perhaps "the day on which I will work" if the 'I' is obvious from the context.

I am wondering if it is possible to say "the day **until which** work will be done" or "the day until which I will work" using that kind of adnominal construction (verb+ㄹ noun) *without* using a word explicitly meaning 'finish'?

Comment: Hi, topo morto. I just edited your post and please review it. My initial reaction to the question is it will entirely depend on context. For example, "일 할 날" in "일 할 날이 얼마 남지 않았다" don't need to be translated to that long English phrase. Can you quote one example sentence?

Comment: @Rathony Thanks for picking up my mistake. it seemed my question wasn't quite clear - hopefully my further edit has clarified it? I'm just wondering if “the day on which work will be done" and “the day until which work will be done” - almost identical constructions in English - need to be translated with slightly different constructions in Korean.

Comment: Now, I understand your question. Not an easy one.

Comment: @Rathony it may be that, as with http://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1713/expressing-from-a-to-b-in-a-more-concise-way, the answer is just "no, you can't do that"!

Comment: I posted an answer and I am not sure I understood your question 100%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you indicated in your comment, the answer is no. You should use a different word depending on context. For example,

> 마감(일)이 언제죠? When is the deadline?

I think '[마감](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=12381100)(일)' could be translated to 'the day until which work will be done' and using '일 할 날' in this context sounds very weird.

'The day until which I will work" could mean '종료일' or '마지막 날'. Without context, it is difficult to know which to use.

Note that '일 할 날', '일 하는 날', '일 한 날', '일 해야 할 날','일 할 수 밖에 없는 날', '일 하지 않으면 안되는 날' and '일 해야 하는데 못하는 날', etc. could have completely different meanings and you need to understand them based on their usages and context.